# I have 4 oneshot systemd services. How to forbid them from running concurrently?

Tags: systemd

I have 4 oneshot systemd services. Two of them for backing up some directories, 2 other for checking those backups. If any of those services tries to run while another is running, it will fail. How do I make it so that no 2 of these services ever run at the same time?

Comment: Maybe use `ConditionPathExists=` with a file as primitive locking mechanism?

Comment: Do the backups take very long to complete? I note the systemd documentation: "it is generally not recommended to use idle or oneshot for long-running services".  What triggers the services to start?

Comment: It'd be useful to know whether the `RemainAfterExit` option is set for these services, as well.